How to remove white color at the bottom screen on iOS using tailwindcss?
I use tailwindcss for styling my web apps and there is always a little but of white space in the bottom screen which becomes visible only after I scroll down on my iPhone browsers. This color overrides my background which should take the full height of the screen. However, images goes on top of the white space. Pic below


Maybe there is some margin at the bottom? And have you done anything with the background-repeat property?
Perhaps you could set a browser on desktop to the same size as your phone?
